# Refactoring a common JSF toolbar with custom logic for each page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have the same standard toolbar with the same commandbutton in all the jsf pages with actions like save , new , search ... and I am looking for a way to refactor it in a xhtml page and include it in every page , the problem is that each page has it's own viewscoped managedbean and the command button action are related to each pages.

Each managedbean implement the interface below that represents the actions

```
public interface ActionAbstract {

public void search(ActionEvent actionEvent);

public void newRecord(ActionEvent actionEvent);

public void clear(ActionEvent actionEvent);

public void remove(ActionEvent actionEvent);

public void searchAdvanced(ActionEvent actionEvent);

public void back(ActionEvent actionEvent);

public void closePage(ActionEvent actionEvent);

public void validate(ActionEvent actionEvent);

public void duplicate(ActionEvent actionEvent);

public void refresh(ActionEvent actionEvent);

}
```

Managed Bean :

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class ExampleBean implements ActionAbstract
```

Toolbar xhtml :

```
<p:toolbar>
<f:facet name="left">
    <p:commandButton title="New" update="@all" icon="fa fa-plus" actionListener="#{ExampleBean.newRecord}" process="@this" />
    <p:commandButton title="Search" update="@all" icon="fa fa-search" actionListener="#{ExampleBean.search}" rendered="#{ExampleBean.showTable}"
                        process="@this" />
    <p:commandButton title="Advanced Search" icon="fa fa-search-plus" actionListener="#{ExampleBean.searchAdvanced}"
                        rendered="#{ExampleBean.showTable}" process="@this" />
    <p:commandButton title="Clear" icon="fa fa-eraser" actionListener="#{ExampleBean.clear}" rendered="#{ExampleBean.showTable}" process="@this" />
    <p:commandButton title="Duplicate" icon="fa fa-copy" actionListener="#{ExampleBean.duplicate}" rendered="#{ExampleBean.showDetail}"
                        process="@this" />
    <p:commandButton title="Validate" icon="fa fa-check" actionListener="#{ExampleBean.validate}" rendered="#{ExampleBean.showDetail}"
                        process="@this" />
    <p:commandButton title="Remove" icon="fa fa-remove" actionListener="#{ExampleBean.remove}" rendered="#{ExampleBean.showDetail}" process="@this" />
    <p:commandButton title="Refresh" icon="fa fa-refresh" actionListener="#{ExampleBean.refresh}" process="@this" />
    <p:commandButton title="Back" update=":form" icon="fa fa-arrow-left" actionListener="#{ExampleBean.back}" rendered="#{ExampleBean.showDetail}"
                        process="@this" />
    <p:commandButton title="Close" icon="fa fa-sign-out" actionListener="#{ExampleBean.closePage}" process="@this" />

</f:facet>
```

it's possible to refactor it ???!!! thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It can absolutely be refactored. This is a case where I'd favor composition over inheritance. You've already got an interface so you could easily use it as an anonymous class and pass it to a composite component. With this approach you could have multiple toolbars on the same page; not that you probably want that but the technique can be applied to other components. Then the only consideration is if you pass in your Ajax attributes (update/process) and the button rendered attributes or if you make them part of your `ActionAbstract`  Interface (if you make them part of the interface it would be a good idea to rename it).

For example, Toolbar Interface

```
package jp.faces.test;

public interface Toolbar {
    public void newRecord();
}
```

Managed Bean; I used lazy instantiation in the getter for the sake of brevity of this example

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {

private Toolbar toolbar = null;

public Toolbar getToolbar(){        
    if(toolbar == null){
        toolbar = new Toolbar() {           
            @Override
            public void newRecord() {
            // custom bean action goes here
        };
    }
    return toolbar;
}
```

The composite

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="toolbar" type="jp.faces.test.Toolbar"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <h:commandButton value="New" actionListener="#{cc.attrs.toolbar.newRecord}"/> 
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

Using it in a Facelet page

```
<comp:toolbar bean="#{testBean.toolbar}"/>
```